# Is there a better way?? SQL

Tags: sql

I'm working on a school assignment on SQL, the way I did it works but, is there a better way??

SQL:

```
SELECT ename, hiredate , TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(hiredate, 6 ), 'DAY') || ', the ' || 
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(hiredate, 6 ), 'DDspth') || ' of ' ||
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(hiredate, 6 ), 'MONTH') || ',' || 
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(hiredate, 6 ), 'YYYY')  AS "REVIEW"
FROM emp;
```

OUTPUT:

```
ENAME           HIREDATE  REVIEW
--------------- --------- ----------------------------------------------
KING            17-NOV-81 MONDAY   , the SEVENTEENTH of MAY      ,1982
BLAKE           01-MAY-81 SUNDAY   , the FIRST of NOVEMBER ,1981
```

Comment: depends ... what's the question?

Comment: No one ever does this in SQL. The better way is using the client language or tool to convert the datetime value to a string after you've retrieved it. What you have a silly problem assigned to give you some practice with the functions. The only thing I might do different is RTRIM() away some of those extra spaces.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 2):

You can include the character literal parts in the format string by enclosing them in double quotes:

```
SELECT ename, hiredate,
       TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(hiredate, 6 ), 'DAY "the" DDspth "of" MONTH, YYYY') AS REVIEW
FROM emp
```

Output:

```
ENAME   HIREDATE                REVIEW
KING    1981-11-17T00:00:00Z    MONDAY the SEVENTEENTH of MAY , 1982
BLAKE   1981-05-01T00:00:00Z    SUNDAY the FIRST of NOVEMBER , 1981
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/895b03/3)

Comment: Thank you so much!! you way is better and shorter